# className() css styling not being displayed

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I am trying to add styling after the user clicks the submit. When the user clicks, selects or inputs in the form remove that specific box-shadow.

Currently, I am doing the following approach to add the styling. However, it appears that when I do this approach, it does add the class but not the styling itself:

```
var name = document.getElementById("name");

name.classList.add += " error";
```

I also tried the Jquery approach to add the class but the same issue occurs:

```
$("#name").addClass("error");
```

Here is my styling:

```
   /***Box Shadow***/
.shadow {
   -moz-box-shadow:    inset 0 0 10px #D9EDFE !important;
   -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #D9EDFE !important;
   box-shadow:         inset 0 0 10px #D9EDFE !important;
} 
.shadow input[type="text"]:focus,
.shadow input[type="email"]:focus,
.shadow textarea:focus,
.shadow select:focus {
   -moz-box-shadow:    inset 0 0 10px #00FFFF !important;
   -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #00FFFF !important;
   box-shadow:         inset 0 0 10px #00FFFF !important;
   background-color: white !important;
}
.error input[type="text"],
.error input[type="email"],
.error textarea,
.error select {
   -moz-box-shadow:    inset 0 0 10px #000000 !important;
   -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000000 !important;
   box-shadow:         inset 0 0 10px #000000 !important;
   background-color: white !important;
}
```

Part of the form where I am trying to implement adding the class:

```
<input type="text" class="shadow" name="Name" id="name" placeholder="Your Name *" maxlength="50">
```

And the following is the functions

```
function checkForm(){
 //The form is blank
  if(name_value == '' && email_value == '' && info_value == '' && list_value == "") {
    alert("Error");
    document.getElementById("myform").focus();

    return highlightAll();      
  }
}
function highlightAll(){
    var name = document.getElementById("name");
    var name = $("#DropList").val();
    //var email = document.getElementById("email");


        $("#name").addClass("error");
        //name.classList.add += " error";
        email.className += " error";
        //info_value.className += " error";
        //list_value.className += " error";

        return false;
    }
```

Any help would be appreciated. Really stuck why its not working

Comment: `name.classList.add += " error";` is wrong syntax. `name.classList.add("error");` is correct.

Answer (score 0):

in your css use `<selector>.error`

```
input[type="text"].error,
input[type="email"].error,
textarea.error,
select.error {
   -moz-box-shadow:    inset 0 0 10px #000000 !important;
   -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000000 !important;
   box-shadow:         inset 0 0 10px #000000 !important;
   background-color: white !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The `error` and `shadow` classes are currently being applied to the parent of the input. `.error input[type=text]` would mean a [descendant selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Descendant_selectors).

So, when you add a class, you have to add it to the parent of the input component.

```
<div id="name">
  <input type="text" class="shadow" name="Name" placeholder="Your Name *" maxlength="50">
</div>
```

Also, javascript version of adding class is simple as

```
name.classList.add('error');
```

Answer (score 0):

(1) The syntax you are using in your css -- for example, ".error textarea" -- translates to "apply this style to any children of elements with the class .error if those children are textareas."

(2) In order to apply a style to an element that has a specific class (continuing with the example above), you would use textarea.error. This translates to "apply this style to elements with the class error."

So, as suggested, you can modify your html to make each of the relevant elements children of element with the id "name" and apply the .error class to that parent using #1 above, or alternatively, apply the error class directly to each of the elements where the box shadow should be removed using #2 above.

In addition, a box shadow can be removed by simply setting that css property to "none".

Comment: @ Greg Brodzik: Thank you. I will keep that in mind. Thank you for the explanation